# Unexpected results when passing webcam frames to object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection, webcam

### Background

I have a well-trained `ssd320x320` tensorflow model from [tensorflow-zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md). The reports are pretty good as the train log indicates a low `loss` and the eval log indicates that 7 out of 9 test images were detected successfully. The model was trained with `GPU` and was saved as `ckpt3`.

The goal is to detect when a person "likes" with their hand.

### Problem

Loading a model from its  last checkpoint works well, and I achieved detection with the following function:

```
    def test1(self):
        # Works great
        for img_path in glob.glob("test_dir\*.jpg"):
            plt.figure()
            plt.imshow(self.get_image_np_with_detections(self._load_image_into_numpy_array(img_path)))
            plt.show()

# Note that get get_image_np_with_detections() is the detection @tf.function() 
# as it is written in tensorflow documentation, with no changes.
# _load_image() function simply returns np.array(Image.open(path))
```

Object detection **in image** was *successfuly* achieved in `test1`.
Problem is that I *failed* to detect an object in **webcam frames**.

From another function, which opens my webcam, I call the same detection function for each frame. This function is failing, as not even one green detection box appears on the screen.

```
    def open_webcam(self):
        # Doesn't show detection green boxes at all
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, image_np = cap.read()
            im_detected = self.get_image_np_with_detections(image_np)
            cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(im_detected, (800, 600)))
        # release, destroy...
```

### Where is the problem

During my debug, I have saved **screenshots** from my webcam, while running the `open_webcam()` function (took a screenshot every `1-2` seconds). The screenshots were saved into `test_dir`, and then were processed to `test1`. The test was successful as **all** screenshots were marked with a green detection box (hand-like-sign).

This test indicates that the problem regards the way I pass frames to the function, as all the frames were successfully detected in the `test1` approach, but not in real-time. To summarize:

- I failed to detect a like-sign in a webcam frame (real-time).
- I saved the frame inside `test_dir`, with a unique-id.
- I managed to detect a like-sign after opening the `jpg`, in `test1()` (9/10 screenshots).

### I have tried to...

- pass frames as `numpy array` with no luck.
- Expand the dimensions as mentioned in tf-documentation, again, with no luck.

### Note that...

- I have only 1 label, which is `Like` (hand-sign).
- I used around 25 train images, and 9 test images.
- As mentioned, the model works great when opening saved `jpg` files. Eval report looks good.
- PY is `3.7`, TF is `2.7`, CV is `4.5.5`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried saving the `im_detected` as images and seeing if they have the detections?

Comment: Yes, there're saved with no detections. Though opening the images with `test1()` detect all objects (as I mentioned), with very good accuracy. This is why I'm lost...

Comment: Can you please show the contents of this function `self._load_image_into_numpy_array`

Comment: it is mentioned under the comment section. It returns `np.array(Image.open(path))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow model is most likely to be trained on RGB images, while cv2 works with BGR. Try

```
image_np  = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Also, model may be trained on normalized images, so, if changing BGR to RGB doesn't help, try

```
image_np = image_np / 255.
```

Comment: Hero! Well I was trying to detect BGR images, oops... After coverting to RGB and settings the `min_score` value, my program works perfect, thanks to you.